# Avoid Killing an Activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-layout

I load data in to a ListView from the server and the way I've implemented it, when I press the back button or the Home Up button, it kills the view thereby forcing the app to reload the data from the server again on NEXT startup of the same view.

My code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //super.onBackPressed();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I would like my view to retain the ListView and its data and still have the data intact when the user comes back to the same view from another view (without having to refresh it every time the view is opened)

How do I modify my code to achieve this? Do I need a SQLite database to sync the data? I've seen apps like Instagram do this with their 'Direct Message' views and their Settings views.

**EDIT**

Just adding another question to the previous one, how does facebook and instagram retain the synced data (Newsfeed items) even after the app is exited? When a user returns to the app, the app maintains the previously synced items even when there's no internet available. Just another question.

Comment: use cursorAdapter and observer pattern

Comment: Saving on preferences or local database is not an option? if you save what you retrieve from web in preferences (for example), once you come back to this activity (or view) you just need to check if you already downloaded data or not. If you already have it, just displayed it in your ListView.

Comment: "how does facebook and instagram retain the synced data" - A combination of techniques, mainly saving the view data to the saved instance state bundle and local cache sqlite databases. Check out the onSaveInstanceState activity/fragment callback and work with parcelables to restore your ui easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't work against the framework. Doing this the way you are suggesting is shoe-horning old desktop programming practices into the android world. Bad idea.

To properly do what you want you need some sort of cache, either in-memory (as in your data provider having an array/list of the latest data it got from the server) or a local database (sqlite, couchbase...) so you don't incur the cost of a server round trip.

If your data is very volatile don't bother with databases, they're going to make your job very hard. On the other hand if your data is constant or nearly unchanging a local database will give you very good performance. The basic idea to implement such a cache is to first lookup the data on it, querying the server if you don't find the data or it is too old/invalid (purging it as well) storing the new data and returning it.

I'm on mobile so I can't give you an example right now, sorry. Have fun.